# How to extract embedded logo in PDF using PDFBox?

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

I need to extract the logo from a PDF for comparison, but the logo is embedded in the PDF, and `getImages()` method is not recognizing the logo. Is there any method to extract the embedded logo?

Comment: Please share the pdf. A logo must not be a image. It can be vector graphics.

Comment: Or it may be in another form xobject or in a pattern or a type 3 font.

Comment: ... or a character in a corporate font.